# How to quickly render 2D/3D Mathematical curve animations without the shadow details

Tags: bezier-curves, mathematics

I am thinking of starting a new YouTube Channel where I'll be doing Math videos. So I'll be doing things like animating curves, similar to the picture attached below. So I don't need much of the shadow details and the textures since it would be quite sleek. Normally Cycles Animation takes hours to render. How can I speed up this process?

[image]

Comment: By the way this picture made with a python library [manim](https://github.com/3b1b/manim). Famous math YouTuber 3blue1brown using manim to make these video.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Eevee rendering (Blender 2.8) with the following base setting. Eevee is physically less accurate than Cycles but much faster.

[image]

The setting is very basic:

[image]

- Material: just use colors as you don't want shadows/shaders (bottom of the image above)
- Wireframe: use a wireframe modifier (on the right in the image)

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot, that helped. Just one more question, how do I do an all round lighting. Such that all the surfaces' colors are properly visible? Normally the surface on the opposite side of the light source becomes black. That doesn't help while drawing a 3D graph

Comment: Yet another question , how do I draw the corresponding coordinate axes?

Comment: @AdityaGhosh The setting in the answer is not "light sensible" because it does not use a shader, but only a color. So, I'm not sure I understand the question in your comment. I will edit the answer so that you can get the blender file.

Comment: For the axis, just use some very thin cylinders + cone + eventually a text.

Comment: I solved it by turning on Environment Lighting. Now all the parts of the graph are evenly lit.

Comment: About the axes, is there an option to get the original axis used by Blender to draw the graph? Like one with graduations on them and with values.

Comment: Not in the rendering as far as I know.

Comment: Okay. Thanks a lot for you help.